# Jquery Validation, Get button clicked in submitHandler()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have two buttons on the from `type='Submit''`
After the validation, in `submitHandler` I want to get which one of these button is clicked.

And depending on this, i want to disable that button.

### Handler

```
$("#add_customer").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        annual_sales_weight: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }

    },
    errorClass: "help-inline",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: highlightJquery,
    unhighlight: Unhilight,
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        var btn = $(form).find('button');
        disable(btn)
        sendAjaxRequest(url,data=form.serialize());

    }
});
```

### HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="add" type="submit"> Submit</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="prospect" type="submit"> Submit & Add prospect</button>
```

Comment: post the root of the function, where this handler is called.

Comment: Added the edit. please find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two `submit` buttons on your form so by the time you get to the `submitHandler` it's too late.  If you want to know which button is clicked you'll have to capture that event ahead of time.

Change them both to `type="button"` so you can control the submit.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="add" type="button">Submit</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="prospect" type="button">Submit &amp; Add prospect</button>
```

Then add this...

```
$('button[name="add"], button[name="prospect"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#myform').valid()) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#myform').submit();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/etHcZ/**

Comment: This doesn't send which button was clicked on server. I mean POST did not contain the button information in the POST data. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Clayton, in all fairness, your original question (now over 18 moths old) mentions nothing about the `post` array.  Nor did you have any problem with this answer since it was the accepted answer for a year and a half.

Comment: Someone just wrote to me and said to review the answer; that if it is the correct and most appropriate, so i just changed it what i was expecting. No hard feelings . +1 though

Comment: @Clayton, it's not about hard feelings.  It's about the question and answer making sense together.  In this case, your question mentions nothing about needing to obtain the button within the POST array.  It only asks about how to capture which button within the validation plugin and that is exactly what was answered here.

Answer (score 12):

In [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js) you could use an undocumented feature of the validate plugin.

```
submitHandler: function(form){              
    var submitButtonName =  $(this.submitButton).attr("name");

... rest of code
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and didn't want to rely on another event firing off to ensure that I had the right value. As it happens validate.js will add the value of the button pressed as a hidden field on the form right before it calls the submitHandler:

```
return n.settings.submitHandler ? 
  (n.submitButton && (i = e("<input type='hidden'/>").attr("name",
   n.submitButton.name).val(e(n.submitButton).val()).appendTo(n.currentForm))
```

It then calls the submitHandler with the form as the first argument.

It is worth knowing that if you then modify the form this newly appended hidden field is removed! In this case you can retrieve it first and then append it back again...

```
submitHandler: function(myForm) {
  var button = $(myForm).find('input[type=hidden][name=mySubmitButtonName]');
  // .. do something with myForm
  $(myForm).append(button) && myForm.submit();
}
```

I hope that helps someone. :-)

Comment: Helps it does. That's a great find.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with identifying the button through event object. Since the answer given by "Christopher Wigginton" is a gud one except it gives me "undefined" on first click.

```
$(event.target).attr('name');
```

**Full example:**

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#btnSaveDraft, #btnSendNotes", function (event) {


    $('#frmThanksNote').validate({// initialize the plugin
        ignore: [],
        debug: false,
        rules: {
           ....
        },
        messages: {
           ....
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          ....
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            var submitButtonName =  $(event.target).attr("id");

            if(submitButtonName == 'btnSaveDraft'){
                saveNotes();
            }else if(submitButtonName == 'btnSendNotes'){
                saveNotes(true);
            }

        },

    });
});
```

Comment: If you add


event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

to the errorPlacement function, you prevent the form from submitting if there is an error (in code or otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

```
//make sure this code executes after dom loads
$(function () {

   //all submits inside 'form' 
   var _buttons = $('input[type="submit"]', form);

   //all buttons inside 'form' 
   var _buttons = $('button', form);

   //attach a click handler

   _buttons.on("click", function () {
       //the current button that called this handler
       var _currentButton = $(this);

       //do stuff...

       //disable button
       _currentButton.attr("disabled", true);

       //submit form
       form.submit();
   });
});
```

here is an example:

<kbd>[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/q6Tbn/)</kbd>

Comment: I am using HTML `<button>` not `<input>` so i guess this is not going to work.

Comment: well simply use a different selector, i have updated the answer

Comment: forgot to mention, the example above disables the button before submitting the form instead of in the submit handler, same result but easier to find the calling button

Comment: You've defined `var _buttons` twice.

Comment: @Sparky its just an example so he could choose whichever he needs.

Comment: This doesn't send which button was clicked on server. I mean POST did not contain the button information in the POST data. Any suggestions? –

Comment: Of course it doesn't, because thats not what this question was about. However, Your solution that you have posted is a good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to work for me.

You can add a hidden field in the form, in the line just above the submit, which will be sent along:

```
$('.dp-blog-form').append('<input type="hidden" name="theButton" value="'+ this.value +'"/>');
```

Comment: How can I do that in jquery validate - submitHandler?