# jQuery Validation: in "rules: {..}" determine which Submit was clicked (one of several)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

There are similar threads on determining which Submit was clicked from `submitHander(form)`:
[Jquery Validation, Get button clicked in submitHandler()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948247/jquery-validation-get-button-clicked-in-submithandler) Thanks to having `form` we can call an undocumented feature, `var submitButtonName =  $(this.submitButton).attr("name");`, which tells us this info.

But I need to determine which Submit was clicked from `rules: {..}`. I have a field whose validation depends on whether the Submit clicked was a real "Submit" or "Save Draft." This field may or may not undergo Required validation.

```
      rules: {
          //... 
          certifyStmt: {
              required: submitClicked /* assuming there's a var called "submitClicked" - Submit ONLY
                                      otherwise false */
          }
      },
```

Nothing is available here, and the code `$(this.submitButton).attr("name");` doesn't work. I tried setting  a hidden var on `onClick` but no success.

```
                <input type="hidden" id="saveOrSubmitClicked" value="" />
                <input type="submit" ... onclick="setSaveOrSubmit('submit');"/>
                <input type="submit" ... onclick="setSaveOrSubmit('save');"/>

                function setSaveOrSubmit(str) {
                    $('#saveOrSubmitClicked').val(str);
                    alert('Set: ' + $('#saveOrSubmitClicked').val());
                }
```

This doesn't work because although the var gets set, checking it in `rules: {}` as follows does not produce the right result. Maybe the current value isn't available in `rules` execution.

```
          certifyStmt: {
              required: $('#saveOrSubmitClicked').val() === 'submitRankingWishLists'
          }
```

My preference would be not to change the Submit's to Button's.

Comment: I am confused; since you are using jQuery, is there something preventing you from using: `var submitButtonName = $('#saveOrSubmitClicked').val();` and obtain this value? - do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, I never get to set that value; the function isn't executed. So the value is unavailable.

Comment: how are you invoking the rules? can you add a [mre]? For example, are you initializing the validate plugin correctly?  do you get any errors in console?

Comment: I see, you are submitting the form outside of jquery (the function is not 'registered' with jquery) so the value is not found in the validation portion.  Please post a [mre] and a solution will be added quickly

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I think I register the rule at a time when the variable isn't available yet. I need to check it dynamically. I'd need some time to set up a sandbox example.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the solution, dynamically add/remove this rule depending on which Submit is clicked:

```
<input type="submit" ... onclick="addCertifyStmtValidation();" >
<input type="submit" ... onclick="removeCertifyStmtValidation();" >

function addCertifyStmtValidation() {
    $("#certifyStmtCheckbox").rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
}

function removeCertifyStmtValidation() {
    $("#certifyStmtCheckbox").rules('remove');
}
```